# bash variable not available after running script

Tags: bash, variables, terminal

I have a shell script that assigns my IP address to a variable, but after running the script, I cannot access the variable in bash. If I put an echo in the script, it will print the variable, but it does not save it after the script is done running.

Is there a way to change the script to access it after it runs?

```
ip=$(/sbin/ifconfig | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v 127 | cut -d":" -f2)
```

I am using terminal on a Mac.

Answer (score 3):

A script by default runs in a a child process, which means the current (calling) shell cannot see its variables.

You have the following options:

- Make the script *output* the information (to stdout), so that the calling shell can capture it and assign it to a variable of its own. This is probably the cleanest solution.

  ```
  ip=$(my-script)
  ```
- *Source* the script to make it run in the *current* shell as opposed to a child process. Note, however, that *all* modifications to the shell environment you make in your script then affect the current shell.

  ```
  . my-script # any variables defined (without `local`) are now visible
  ```
- Refactor your script into a *function* that you define in the *current shell* (e.g., by placing it in `~/.bashrc`); again, all modifications made by the function will be visible to the current shell:

  ```
  # Define the function
  my-func() { ip=$(/sbin/ifconfig | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v 127 | cut -d":" -f2); }

  # Call it; $ip is implicitly defined when you do.
  my-func
  ```

---

As an aside: You can simplify your command as follows:

```
/sbin/ifconfig | awk '/inet / && $2 !~ /^127/ { print $2 }'
```